# Bluetooth 4 compatibility

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can BTLE devices be discoverable by BT2.0 devices? If so, do BTLE devices consume low power during inquiry scan? How much power do they consume for that operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - BTLE and BT Classic (2.0) cannot talk to each other.

Comment: Although, there are dual-mode devices that can do both Bluetooth BR/EDR and Bluetooth low energy. However, if a dual-mode device connects to another dual-mode device, then they are mandated to use BR/EDR for their connections and not LE.